# How to connect both a bluetooth receiver and a amplifier to the same power input?

Tags: batteries, bluetooth, speakers, charging

Dear users of this forum,

I am new to this so I apologize in advance for any rookie mistakes.
I am building a portable speaker of which I connected the speakers and the amp already.

I am looking for a way however to connect the amp to a battery pack or accu. I have been told I should use a 12 volt 5 amp battery. The bluetooth receiver I intend to plug into the amplifier needs power too and I have no clue how to wire it to the battery and if I am able to use the same battery?

All your tips are very welcome!

Luke

I will be using a bluetooth receiver similar to this:

http://www.lightinthebox.com/nl/3-5-mm-draadloze-bluetooth-muziek-ontvanger-bluetooth-audio-adapter_p1131211.html?currency=EUR&litb_from=paid_adwords_shopping&utm_source=google_shopping&utm_medium=cpc&adword_mt=&adword_ct=87561882434&adword_kw=&adword_pos=1o4&adword_pl=&adword_net=g&adword_tar=&adw_src_id=1810908567_301588514_21687237914_pla-117284547555&gclid=CLO5yrqOh84CFQ8z0wodalMIMA

And this amp:

[https://www.amazon.com/Lepai-LP-2020A-Tripath-Class-T-Amplifier/dp/B0049P6OTI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0049P6OTI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, the bluetooth module runs off a USB socket, so needs 5V. Just use something like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/12V-Boat-Car-Cigarette-Lighter-Socket-2-1A-Dual-USB-Car-Charger-Power-Outlet-/391312261382?hash=item5b1c074106:g:UwkAAOSw7hRWOs1B).

When you say '5A battery', do you mean 5Ah, or just capable of supplying 5A for a decent amount of time? If so, how long? You need to do a bit calculation and work out how long you would like the system to work before needing a charge.

Take the 5A and multiply by the number of hours you have above. That will give you a rough idea of the size of battery you need.

Eg, say you want to run for 5 hours, 5A x 5Hrs = 25Ah. Obviously the longer you want the system to be autonomous, the bigger (and more expensive) the battery.

Once you´ve done that, using the same battery shouldn´t be a problem as the module won´t draw that much current, although it may be worth checking that before you buy it.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I meant it should be capable of supplying 5A for a decent amount of time. I will start searching for a a 12V 5A and about 30Ah battery!